# syntax error, unexpected '"/> '

Tags: php

```
    <?php 
        global $connection;
            $query = "SELECT * FROM products";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);;
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                do {
                echo '
                <li>
                <div class="block-images">
                <img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\swet\Yii2\Начало\tovary\' .$row["image"]. '"/>
                </div>
ошибка в этой строке   <p class="style-title"><a href="">' .$row["title"]. '</a></p>
                <a class="cart-style"></a>
                <p class="style-price"><strong></strong>руб.</p>
                <div class="description">'.$row["description"].'</div>
                </li>
    ';
                }
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
            }

        ?>
```

никак не могу понять почему ошибка...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
global $connection;
$query = "SELECT * FROM products";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query); //<-- Удалить лишнюю точку с запятой.
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    do {
        echo '
        <li>
         <div class="block-images">
          <img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\swet\Yii2\Начало\tovary\"'.$row["image"].'"/>
         </div>
         <p class="style-title"><a href="">' .$row["title"]. '</a></p>
         <a class="cart-style"></a>
         <p class="style-price"><strong></strong>руб.</p>
         <div class="description">'.$row["description"].'</div>
        </li>';
    }
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
}

?>
```

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: @Даниил $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) **;** ;